# Bluetooth headset set-up problem

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I'm having this problem when I try to set-up my bluetooth headset (an Avantree audition Pro, which is very nice btw), and it pairs properly, but when I go to sound settings, it doesn't show in list of output devices. The only thing I tried so far is make `AutoConnect=true` in `/etc/audio/bluetooth.conf`, but it doesn't change anything.

Any other ideas? Thank you very much.

P.D.: I'm using an old Lenovo Thinkpad edge 13" 0196-A13.

tony@ToNy:~$ pactl list short | grep bluetooth
7   module-bluetooth-policy

Comment: Please edit question to add `pactl list short | grep bluetooth` terminal results

Comment: That's what I got:
7 module-bluetooth-policy

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to

```
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

You will likely have to disconnect from the bluetooth headset and reconnect

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very much (Y)